# How to retrieve a webpage with C#?

Tags: c#, http

How to retrieve a webpage and diplay the html to the console with C# ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the `System.Net.WebClient` class.

```
System.Console.WriteLine(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url));
```

Comment: It would be synchronous, though. Meaning it will only display data after the entire page has been loaded.

Answer (score 19):

I have knocked up an example:

```
WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create("http://www.msn.com");
WebResponse resp = r.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Here is another option, using the WebClient this time and do it asynchronously:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Net.WebClient c = new WebClient();
    c.DownloadDataCompleted += 
         new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadDataCompleted);
    c.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.msn.com"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void c_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, 
                                    DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Result));
}
```

The second option is handy as it will not block the UI Thread, giving a better experience.

Comment: I did not specify that my example was for the sole purposes of using with a console application.

Comment: I agree but I think the exact example you mentioned demonstrate something specifically *wrong* (in console version only): pressing a key before the URL is fetched causes the console to be closed before anything is written to it. Changing the name of `Main` method better demonstrates your intention.

Comment: It was just to convey the example of the Async mehtod option.  Fair do's I could have extracted the method into its own I suppose. Either way, I just did it quick to get my example out there. I had no intention that "pressing a key" helped get the html of the request.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: That's Fine :) Sorry if this bothered you. I didn't mean it.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Save HTML code to a local file.
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\htmlFile.html");

// Without saving it.
string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
```